Outlook.exe keeps launching unprompted with -embedded flag, issue tracing with Procmon.exe
I don't use Outlook (local) app, but recently it keeps popping up, asking me to choose a profile on Windows 11. I assume something I've updated recently has tried to set up a helper hook (e.g. Adobe).  Or it might be tied to a backend update for the new Outlook rollout by Microsoft as we do use Microsoft 365 Office suite.  Or... could be Windows Defender trying to scan proactively, as I do see Defender scan events taking place within the same time range.

I keep running procmon.exe in the background to catch the moment when it launches, to look around that event. I see that svchost.exe (with PID 1228) is launching this command line: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE" -Embedding

The problem is that ALL svchost.exe processes are running on PID 1228, and when I go to event properties > process, it's reporting all the many, many things svchost.exe is running:

I did try uninstalling Adobe notification services in my installed apps, but that apparently wasn't the culprit.  Outlook is not in my apps > startup, and I don't see that command line in any scheduled tasks.
I admit my knowledge of procmon.exe is limited: Does anyone know if procmon.exe is able to trace the root cause of this launch (and if so, what steps am I overlooking to reveal that further)?   Thanks!

You saw "We do use Office 365"? Is this a business computer? Also, Task Manager has a Startup section that is a simple way to check for programs the OS will start with each login. Finally, ProcessExplorer will show you the full path for a running application, including which application started it, if there's a "helper" app triggering the Outlook start.

If it's your personal PC, and you don't use it, try removing Outlook (https://www.wikihow.com/Uninstall-Outlook-on-PC-or-Mac). Also, have you tried making another email client, e.g., Thunderbird, the default app?

It’s not Windows Defender.

Do you mean that Outlook opens automatically when you open your PC?

@music2myear Thank you! I forgot about ProcessExplorer; I just downloaded that and verified that the parent (svchost)'s autostart location is: HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\WpnUserService_20fcbf (which is "Windows Push Notifications User Service").  So now I just have to figure out why Windows Push Notifications User Service is trying to launch Outlook (@Christy every few hours or so)

You haven't yet answered all the questions we asked and so we are missing information we need in order to help you. Please read the comments entirely and answer all the questions asked.

@music2myear This is a business computer using Office365, but I do not launch Outlook.  I use Outlook web from Edge browser.  As mentioned from using ProcessExplorer (thank you) - outlook is being launched by svchost.exe, and the autostart location is Windows Push Notifications User Service (though I can't tell what app is trying to use Outlook through this.  If I reboot, Outlook stays unopened for an unspecified period of time, then randomly launches the profile chooser (as I do not use Outlook app).  If I close it, it reopens a few hours later.  lmk if I missed a question. Thanks!

If this is a business computer you need to speak with your designated IT staff. They will have control over your computer in ways we do not know the details of. Questions about business computers are usually off topic here for this reason.
